# Create dynamic <div> and use edit jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html, append

I have problem here. This code creates a dynamic div:

```
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            $('#konf-select-mech').append('<div class="ksm-box"><table><tr><td width="111" class="ksmbt-r1"><span>Otvor '+ pocitadlo++ +':</span></td><td><select class="select-menu1"><option>Vyber mechanizmus</option><option value="Vypinac">Vypínač</option><option value="Zasuvka">Zásuvka</option></select></td><td width="106"><img src="./images/konfsipka.png" alt="" /></td><td><select class="select-menu2"></select></td></tr></table></div>');
        }
```

And I can edit it using javascript:

```
$('.select-menu1').live('click', function() {
        var selectx = $(this).val();
        if(selectx == "Vypínač") {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.select-menu2 option').remove();
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.select-menu2').append('<option value="Jednopackovy">Jednopáčkový</option><option value="Krizovy">Krížový</option><option value="Dvojpackovy">Dvojpáčkový</option><option value="Tlacitko">Tlačítko</option><option value="Stmievac">Stmievač</option>');
        }
        else if (selectx == "Zásuvka") {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.select-menu2 option').remove();
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.select-menu2').append('<option value="Zasuvka230V">Zásuvka 230V</option><option value="ZasuvkaTVRD">Zásuvka TV+RD</option><option value="ZasuvkaTVRDSAT">Zásuvka TV+RD+SAT</option><option value="DatZasuvJedFTP">Dátová zásuvka jednoduchá FTP cat6</option><option value="DatZasuvDvojFTP">Dátová zásuvka dvojitá FTP cat6</option><option value="TelZasuvJedRJ11">Telefónna zásuvka jednoduchá RJ11</option>');
        }
        else if (selectx == "Vyber mechanizmus") {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But it does not work as expected. Not sure what's wrong. Could someone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what does not work correctly?? we cannot read your mind for problem and solution. Please create a proper question so that we help you.

Comment: Do you know what the code is supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.live()`. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Also, change the  selector to `$('.select-menu1 option')`.

Answer (score 0):

If `select-menu1` is a `<select>` element, you should use the event [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of .click() like this:

```
$('.select-menu1').change(function(
  // do something
));
```

**OR**

```
 $('.select-menu1').live('change', function(
  // do something
));
```

Comment: When the div not generate static html so it works. But when it dynamically so it is not. I also tried ".change" and ".on" but still nothing

Comment: @AdamMikó The dynamically generated html should be resolved with the use of .live function. Try setting some alerts in your event to make sure it is fired.